# blog post content via url parameters (meta) in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, parameters, meta-tags

I am trying to create an URL which will set the blog post like `./wp-admin/post-new.php?post_title=title`

I know that post_title, content and excerpt will work for this, but I don't know how to set meta tags.

I need this to create a new posting when clicking on a map (openlayers) and automaticaly set longitude and latitude in meta tags.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose, for auto-post-creating, you should dig [XML-RPC interface](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) first. This tool is not so hard to master and is very powerful.